# Efficient way to filter an array based on element index

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an array of arrays.  So each element of my first array contains a comma separated list of values.  If I use the split function, I can get an array from this comma separated list.  What I need to do is filter out this second array based on element position.  For example only keep columns one, three, five and nine.

One way to do this is loop thru my first array, for each element do a split on the element to get my second array.  Then loop thru this second array, increment a counter to track the current element index.  If the counter is equal to one of the columns I want to keep, then concat the element to a string variable.

This is very inefficient and takes forever to run on large arrays.  Does anyone have any ideas on a better way to do this?  I hope I explained this clearly.

Comment: If you want to explain it clearly, you could post some samples.

Answer (score 0):

There are some built in array actions like “Filter” and “Join” as you mention, but for something this specific I imagine you’ll need to call some code (e.g. azure function) to quickly do manipulation and return result

Answer (score 0):

For the first loop I don't know of any alternate but for second loop, Instead of looping through the second array,you can simply access the elements with index that you require.

Assuming the size is not an issue.

```
string[] Arr1 = new string[] { "0_zero,0_One,0_Two,0_Three,0_Four,0_Five,0_six,0_seven,0_eight,0_nine",
                "1_zero,1_One,1_Two,1_Three,1_Four,1_Five,1_six,1_seven,1_eight,1_nine" };
            string myString = string.Empty;
            foreach(var a in Arr1)
            {
                var sp = a.Split(',');
                myString= string.Concat(myString, sp[0], sp[3], sp[5], sp[9]);                   
            }
            Console.WriteLine(myString); //gives "0_One0_Three0_Five0_nine1_One1_Three1_Five1_nine"
```

In case we're not sure of length of each string, we can use if else ladder with decreasing order from maximum index that we want to use like so

```
foreach(var a in Arr1)
            {
                var sp = a.Split(',');
                int len = sp.Length;
                if (len >= 10)  myString= string.Concat(myString, sp[1], sp[3], sp[5], sp[9]);
                else if (len >= 6) myString = string.Concat(myString, sp[1], sp[3], sp[5]);
                else if (len >= 4) myString = string.Concat(myString, sp[1], sp[3]);
                else if (len >= 2) myString = string.Concat(myString, sp[1]);                        
            }
```

So that we don't face IndexOutofBoundsException